# The method sessionManagement() is undefined for the type HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity>

Tags: spring-boot, spring-oauth2

I am configuring a Spring Boot Oauth2 project an got stuck somewhere at configure method of ResourceServerConfiguration class.

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/oauth/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(
                        new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth/authorize"))
                .disable().headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/hello/")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/secure/**").authenticated();

    }
```

In the above code, although I have imported

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
```

it shows error at sessionManagement() which says that

```
The method sessionManagement() is undefined for the type HeadersConfigurer<HttpSecurity>
```

**Any idea / solution ??**

**Thank you !!**

Comment: `.disable().and().sessionManagemet().` Your IDE should inform you about the available methods.

Comment: It is not informing because I have already imported these two dependencies.
`org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;`

Comment: It has nothing to do with those imports. If you press, generally. [CTRL] + [SPACE] after the method you called you will available options, you will see that `sessionManagement()` isn't an option.

Answer (score 0):

Use the newest Spring Security release version `4.2.3.RELEASE` and you will not have a problem. You should also rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks pablo127, sure I will use new version.